# MatchRegex Поиск символа в строке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, search

У меня есть данные вида `username@email.com,` Как мне сделать поиск `@` до символа `,` с помощью регулярного выражения? Вернуть true/false

Comment: Что должно получиться на выходе? `email.com`? После `,` ничего нет?

Comment: @dIm0n на выходе true или false, Если в строке не найден символ @, то соответственно результат false. после , есть символы, но их нужно проигнорировать

Comment: Почитайте описание метки [tag:регулярные-выражения] https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/регулярные-выражения/info

Comment: @dIm0n хорошо, я добавил метку JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let string = 'username@email.com,username1@email.com,usernamemail.com,username2@email.com,username3@email.com';
let arr = string.split(',');
console.log(arr.map(item => item.includes('@')));
```

Если входные данные это строка, то можно так сделать и в результате будет массив с **true** или **false**